# ERROR in ./~/node-virustotal

Tags: node.js

i start kibana project was error:
  ERROR in ./~/node-virustotal/~/request/lib/har.js
    Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/node-virustotal/node_modules/request/lib
     @ ./~/node-virustotal/~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22

```
ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/forever-agent
 @ ./~/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24

ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/forever-agent
 @ ./~/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24

ERROR in ./~/emailjs/smtp/smtp.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/emailjs/smtp
 @ ./~/emailjs/smtp/smtp.js 7:10-24

ERROR in ./~/emailjs/smtp/message.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/emailjs/smtp
 @ ./~/emailjs/smtp/message.js 3:17-30

ERROR in ./~/emailjs/smtp/smtp.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/emailjs/smtp
 @ ./~/emailjs/smtp/smtp.js 4:10-24

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/tunnel-agent
 @ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24

ERROR in ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/tough-cookie/lib
 @ ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24

ERROR in ./~/imap/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/imap/lib
 @ ./~/imap/lib/Connection.js 1:10-24

ERROR in ./~/imap/lib/Connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/imap/lib
 @ ./~/imap/lib/Connection.js 2:13-27

ERROR in ./~/starttls/lib/starttls.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/starttls/lib
 @ ./~/starttls/lib/starttls.js 20:10-24

ERROR in ./~/starttls/lib/starttls.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/starttls/lib
 @ ./~/starttls/lib/starttls.js 21:10-24

ERROR in ./~/fstream/lib/proxy-writer.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/fstream/lib
 @ ./~/fstream/lib/proxy-writer.js 14:9-22

ERROR in ./~/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/mime
 @ ./~/mime/mime.js 2:9-22

ERROR in ./~/uue/uue.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/uue
 @ ./~/uue/uue.js 1:9-22

ERROR in ./~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/graceful-fs
 @ ./~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22

ERROR in ./~/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/rimraf
 @ ./~/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22

ERROR in ./~/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/mkdirp
 @ ./~/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22

ERROR in ./~/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/graceful-fs
 @ ./~/graceful-fs/fs.js 3:9-22

ERROR in ./~/rimraf/~/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/yangzhenfang/Ekko's kibana5.1.1/kibana/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob
 @ ./~/rimraf/~/glob/glob.js 43:9-22
```

Unhandled rejection Error: Optimizations failure